# How to implement single-sign-on in mvc5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, single-sign-on

I have 4 mvc5 applications and all of them are using active directory authentication ,I want to use single sign on for all those applications.
How to implement SSO?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: If it's an intranet then use Windows authentication and things just work, no real need to code anything.

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure that you are on the same domain (for the cookies to have same domain)
- You will have to configure the applications to use forms authentication because it relies on cookie based authentication.

  `<authenticationmode="Forms"><formsloginUrl="your lgin page here" timeout="2880"domain="your domain name here"/>
  </authentication>`
- All your application should have the same machine key defined in web.config:

  `<machineKeyvalidationKey="282487E295028E59B8F411ACB689CCD6F39DDD21E6055A3EE480424315994760ADF21B580D8587DB675FA02F79167413044E25309CCCDB647174D5B3D0DD9141"decryptionKey="8B6697227CBCA902B1A0925D40FAA00B353F2DF4359D2099"validation="SHA1"/>`

Comment: can you show me the parts of your web.configs where you put the code i wrote?

Comment: <system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="282487E295028E59B8F411ACB689CCD6F39DDD21E6055A3EE480424315994760ADF21B580D8587DB675FA02F79167413044E25309CCCDB647174D5B3D0DD9141"
             decryptionKey="8B6697227CBCA902B1A0925D40FAA00B353F2DF4359D2099" validation="SHA1"/>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All"/>
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>

Comment: can you try to put just <machineKey validationKey="282487E295028E59B8F411ACB689CCD6F39DDD21E6055A3EE480424315994760A‌​DF21B580D8587DB675FA02F79167413044E25309CCCDB647174D5B3D0DD9141" decryptionKey="8B6697227CBCA902B1A0925D40FAA00B353F2DF4359D2099" validation="SHA1"/> in all the web.config (for the 4 applications)